# SharePoint 2013 JS Link edit form control

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-online, jslink

I have below code snippet to make fields in a SharePoint list edit form read only under certain conditions. This works fine but what I would like to know is how I can return the edit control for a certain field if I determine this field should not be made read only?

I know how to return the field value but the user should be able to edit the field. So what should I return on the line with the ????

```
fldCtx.Templates = {};
fldCtx.Templates.OnPostRender = hiddenFieldsOnPostRender;
fldCtx.Templates.Fields = {
  'Title': { 'EditForm': makeFieldReadOnly }
}

function makeFieldReadOnly(ctx) {
    if (ctx.CurrentItem.MakeReadOnly == false) {
        // we don't want this field read only
        return ????;
    } else {
        // make fields read only
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Depending on what type of field you want you can return something like this:

```
return SPClientPeoplePickerCSRTemplate(ctx); // It is for default rendering of people picker.
```

Same can be done for other type of fields from below.

```
                     Text': {
                        'View': RenderFieldValueDefault,
                        'DisplayForm': SPField_FormDisplay_Default,
                        'EditForm': SPFieldText_Edit,
                        'NewForm': SPFieldText_Edit
                    },
                    'Number': {
                        'View': RenderFieldValueDefault,
                        'DisplayForm': SPField_FormDisplay_Default,
                        'EditForm': SPFieldNumber_Edit,
                        'NewForm': SPFieldNumber_Edit
                    },
                    'Integer': {
                        'View': RenderFieldValueDefault,
                        'DisplayForm': SPField_FormDisplay_Default,
                        'EditForm': SPFieldNumber_Edit,
                        'NewForm': SPFieldNumber_Edit
                    },
                    'Boolean': {
                        'View': RenderFieldValueDefault,
                        'DisplayForm': SPField_FormDisplay_DefaultNoEncode,
                        'EditForm': SPFieldBoolean_Edit,
                        'NewForm': SPFieldBoolean_Edit
                    },
                    'Note': {
                        'View': RenderFieldValueDefault,
                        'DisplayForm': SPFieldNote_Display,
                        'EditForm': SPFieldNote_Edit,
                        'NewForm': SPFieldNote_Edit
                    },
                    'Currency': {
                        'View': RenderFieldValueDefault,
                        'DisplayForm': SPField_FormDisplay_Default,
                        'EditForm': SPFieldNumber_Edit,
                        'NewForm': SPFieldNumber_Edit
                    },
                    'File': {
                        'View': RenderFieldValueDefault,
                        'DisplayForm': SPFieldFile_Display,
                        'EditForm': SPFieldFile_Edit,
                        'NewForm': SPFieldFile_Edit
                    },
                    'Calculated': {
                        'View': RenderFieldValueDefault,
                        'DisplayForm': SPField_FormDisplay_Default,
                        'EditForm': SPField_FormDisplay_Empty,
                        'NewForm': SPField_FormDisplay_Empty
                    },
                    'Choice': {
                        'View': RenderFieldValueDefault,
                        'DisplayForm': SPField_FormDisplay_Default,
                        'EditForm': SPFieldChoice_Edit,
                        'NewForm': SPFieldChoice_Edit
                    },
                    'MultiChoice': {
                        'View': RenderFieldValueDefault,
                        'DisplayForm': SPField_FormDisplay_Default,
                        'EditForm': SPFieldMultiChoice_Edit,
                        'NewForm': SPFieldMultiChoice_Edit
                    },
                    'Lookup': {
                        'View': RenderFieldValueDefault,
                        'DisplayForm': SPFieldLookup_Display,
                        'EditForm': SPFieldLookup_Edit,
                        'NewForm': SPFieldLookup_Edit
                    },
                    'LookupMulti': {
                        'View': RenderFieldValueDefault,
                        'DisplayForm': SPFieldLookup_Display,
                        'EditForm': SPFieldLookup_Edit,
                        'NewForm': SPFieldLookup_Edit
                    },
                    'Computed': {
                        'View': RenderFieldValueDefault,
                        'DisplayForm': SPField_FormDisplay_Default,
                        'EditForm': SPField_FormDisplay_Default,
                        'NewForm': SPField_FormDisplay_Default
                    },
                    'URL': {
                        'View': RenderFieldValueDefault,
                        'DisplayForm': SPFieldUrl_Display,
                        'EditForm': SPFieldUrl_Edit,
                        'NewForm': SPFieldUrl_Edit
                    },
                    'User': {
                        'View': RenderFieldValueDefault,
                        'DisplayForm': SPFieldUser_Display,
                        'EditForm': SPClientPeoplePickerCSRTemplate,
                        'NewForm': SPClientPeoplePickerCSRTemplate
                    },
                    'UserMulti': {
                        'View': RenderFieldValueDefault,
                        'DisplayForm': SPFieldUserMulti_Display,
                        'EditForm': SPClientPeoplePickerCSRTemplate,
                        'NewForm': SPClientPeoplePickerCSRTemplate
                    },
                    'DateTime': {
                        'View': RenderFieldValueDefault,
                        'DisplayForm': SPFieldDateTime_Display,
                        'EditForm': SPFieldDateTime_Edit,
                        'NewForm': SPFieldDateTime_Edit
                    },
                    'Attachments': {
                        'View': RenderFieldValueDefault,
                        'DisplayForm': SPFieldAttachments_Default,
                        'EditForm': SPFieldAttachments_Default,
                        'NewForm': SPFieldAttachments_Default
                    }
```

Answer (score 1):

There is a **global** default function *RenderItemTemplate*

```
function makeFieldReadOnly(ctx) {
  if (ctx.CurrentItem.MakeReadOnly == false) {
    // we don't want this field read only
    /*global RenderItemTemplate*/
    return RenderItemTemplate(ctx);
  } else {
    // make fields read only
   }
}
```

The global comment is to calm down JSlint.